# Android - guess script layout direction from current locale

Tags: android, layout, text

Is there a way to get from current Android locale if it is using left to right or right to left layout for text?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution: include google BidiUtils in your project. It has a lot of useful bidi functions, one of them is:

hasAnyRtl